# Function returning a pointer invalidates pointer on second call

Tags: c, pointers, clang

I am debugging/porting some code that I found had a curious, different behavior. What I am trying to determine is the correct behavior for the (any) compiler.

When I have a function that returns a pointer, and it is called twice, the old pointer is overwritten by the new pointer address.   The issue in the sample code that I made is demonstrated by the *byte_to_binary function.  If I use a single `byte_to_binary` function in the `printf("%s\n",byte_to_binary(x));` statement I get this result:

```
00100000
11110000
11011000
11001100
11000110
```

If I use two `byte_to_binary` calls as arguments, as in

```
printf("%s %s\n",byte_to_binary(x),byte_to_binary(z));
```

you end up with the pointer representing z twice, with this output:

```
01100000 01100000
00110000 00110000
00011000 00011000
00001100 00001100
00000110 00000110
```

In many ways, this make sense to me because it seems that the compiler is just reusing the address, but from a code perspective, I would assume that the compiler would just throw two different results on the stack.

This code I present is the most succinct, repeatable explanation that I could come up with after from my original code base.  The original code compiled for Solaris using Sun's CC sometime in 2006 (I no longer have access to the machine), and I am now using clang-700.1.81.  The original code resulted in my expected behavior for returning the pointer to the x and then z conversion.

```
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
const char *byte_to_binary(unsigned char x)
{
    static char bits[9];
    bits[0] = '\0';
    int z;
    for (z=128;z>0;z>>= 1)
    {  strcat(bits, ((x & z) == z) ? "1" : "0");  }
    return bits;
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) {


    unsigned char i;
    unsigned char x=0x80;
    unsigned char z=(3)<<5; 
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        x=x-z;
        printf("%s %s\n",byte_to_binary(x),byte_to_binary(z));
        //printf("%s\n",byte_to_binary(x));
        z = z >> 1;
    }

}
```

The ultimate question is, should this line

```
printf("%s %s\n",byte_to_binary(x),byte_to_binary(z));
```

indeed return use the pointer of byte_to_binary(z) twice?

Comment: Using `strcat()` for this is completely unnecessary. Also, your `bits` array will change on every call to `byte_to_binary`, pass an array to it to avoid this.

Comment: Behavior is defined. The order of the calls is unspecified and that is it. Before printf even starts looking at the bytes, the two function already returned.

Comment: @2501 Isn't the unspecified order yielding undefined result?

Comment: @EugeneSh. No. For example, simply adding two variables, `a = b+c` is unspecified behavior, because it isn't specified which one is evaluated first.

Comment: @2501 Yes, but in that case there is are no side-effects to either evaluation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. There are no side effects. The pointer isn't modified.

Comment: Hm. Looks like I've miss-looked something here.. Will remove my comment for now

Comment: @EugeneSh. No problem, keep researching.

Comment: I just wanted to add that there are no side-effects happening on the same object that are also unsequenced, because the two pointers are two distinct objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the return value of `byte_to_binary` as a parameter to `printf`, the only result the compiler "throws on the stack" is the *pointer* value returned by `byte_to_binary`. Your `byte_to_binary` function is deliberately implemented to return *the same* pointer every time it is called. It returns a pointer to *the same* internal static buffer `bits` every time. In other words, each subsequent call to `byte_to_binary` *overwrites* the result of the previous call to `byte_to_binary`.

This immediately means that you generally cannot have more than one call to `byte_to_binary` in a single expression. Your `printf` will always print the same string twice. Which result will "win" this "competition: - `byte_to_binary(x)` or `byte_to_binary(z)` - is unspecified.

And even if you follow the convention of calling `byte_to_binary` no more than once in each expression, you still have to remember that the lifetime of the result pointed to by the returned pointer extends only till the next call to `byte_to_binary`.

Returning a pointer to a single internal static buffer is not a very viable technique in cases like that. If you really crave the convenience of not having to worry about buffer management, at least use a circular collection of static buffers. E.g. something like

```
const char *byte_to_binary(unsigned char x)
{
    static char buffers[5][9];
    static unsigned ibuffer = 0;

    char *bits = buffers[ibuffer++];
    ibuffer %= sizeof buffers / sizeof *buffers;

    ...

    return bits;
}
```

This will produce expected results in your `printf` call. It relies on 5 buffers used in circular fashion. Of course this approach also has its drawbacks, but it is pretty viable in auxiliary code.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the content of the address returned by the function, in your second call, then `printf` print the same twice.

Answer (score -1):

When you make this call:

```
printf("%s %s\n",byte_to_binary(x),byte_to_binary(z));
```

Both calls to `byte_to_binary` return a pointer to the same static array `bits`.  So whichever call was executed last will dictate what `bits` contains.

The order in which function parameters is evaluated is undefined, so you can't depend on either one executing first.

So you can't call this function twice in one line.  You need to split it up to get the results you expect:

```
printf("%s\n",byte_to_binary(x));
printf("%s\n",byte_to_binary(z));
```